# Delete multiple datas sharing a same child from Firebase - Java - orderByKey

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following Firebase Database :

[image: Database picture]

I need to delete all the entries/database objects sharing the same "date_cours" type.

I tried the following method to delete all the entries sharing the same date_cours "10/09/2018", for example :

```
private void Delete_CR_Lessons(Date date) {
    final String date_a_supprimer_string = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT).format(date);

    DatabaseReference drTest = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("cours");

    drTest.child("date_cours").orderByKey().equalTo("10/09/2018")
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    Log.i("Tag", "test1");

                    for (DataSnapshot postsnapshot :dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Log.i("Tag", "test2");
                        String key = postsnapshot.getKey();
                        dataSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Log.w("TAG: ", databaseError.getMessage());
                }
            });
}//fin de la methode Delete_CR_Lessons
```

I have no error during the execution of the method.
In the Logs, I can see my Log "test1" but not the log "test2".

Does anyone know what I am missing ?

Comment: equalTo("01/10/2018")....

Comment: What exactly is the value of your dataSnapshot? (Are you actually getting anything with your query?)

Comment: @Mathias I have posted you an answer check the code below it contains path fixed note: `orderByChild`

Comment: @André Kool : Thanks for your comment! A contributor solves the problem. See below reponse if your are interested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are providing wrong path and than you are trying to delete wrong `datasnapshot` value for example try to use: `postsnapshot.getRef().removeValue();` instead of `dataSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();` because `dataSnapshot` doesn't point to the value which you want to delete. That is why you used `for` loop to get all value nodes from your database. Check code below:

```
DatabaseReference drTest = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("cours");

drTest.orderByChild("date_cours").equalTo("01/10/2018")
        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                Log.i("Tag", "test1");

                for (DataSnapshot postsnapshot :dataSnapshot.getChildren())  {
                    Log.i("Tag", "test2");
                    String key = postsnapshot.getKey();
                    postsnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
                }

            }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.w("TAG: ", databaseError.getMessage());
            }

        });
```